# SQL Server 2019 - Pivot on Weekday for Multiple Weeks

Tags: sql, pivot, sql-server-2019

I have researched this on StackOverflow but cannot find exactly what I need. I wish to write a query that will format vertically-oriented data to a horizontal format.

Here is the table with the data:

```
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TEMP_PCHG2](
    [dseqkey] [int] NULL,
    [SDate] [date] NULL,
    [PctChg] [real] NULL,
    [weekDay] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [dateGap] [int] NULL
  ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The the dseqkey column is contiguous although SDate excludes weekends and holidays. The dateGap column contains 2 for a normal weekend and 3 if there is a holiday on Fri or Mon. All help is appreciated.

Here is sample data from the above

[image]

Here is the desired result

[image]

Here is SQL I have written with a pivot. However, it does not produce the desired results

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        SPXDate, weekDay, PctChg, dseqkey
    FROM 
        TEMP_SPX_PCHG2
) t
PIVOT(
    MAX(PctChg) 
    FOR weekDay IN (
        [MON], 
        [TUE], 
        [WED], 
        [THU], 
        [FRI])
) AS pivot_table;
```

Comment: Your desired result doesn't really make sense as a SQL table.  Normally, a result set has a fixed set of columns and rows with data.  The data is compatible, so you wouldn't have a date in one row and a number in the "next" row.

Answer (score 0):

You could structure your data with a date column which is the beginning of the week and the day-of-week columns for that week.  This isn't exactly the format you are specifying, but it certainly seems reasonable.

Something like this:

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, 1 - DATEPART(weekday, PXDate), PXDate)) as weekStart,
       MAX(CASE WHEN weekDay = 'MON' THEN PctChg END) as Mon,
       MAX(CASE WHEN weekDay = 'TUE' THEN PctChg END) as Tue,
       MAX(CASE WHEN weekDay = 'WED' THEN PctChg END) as Wed,
       MAX(CASE WHEN weekDay = 'THU' THEN PctChg END) as Thu,
       MAX(CASE WHEN weekDay = 'FRI' THEN PctChg END) as Fri
FROM TEMP_SPX_PCHG2
GROUP BY DATEADD(day, 1 - DATEPART(weekday, PXDate), PXDate))
ORDER BY DATEADD(day, 1 - DATEPART(weekday, PXDate), PXDate));
```

Note:  The specific start of the week depends on the `DATEFIRST` parameter.  I would expect Mon-Fri to be in the same week.